# Calculating the number of zero crossings in a list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the number of zero crossing in a list. The code I am using is:

```
for i in range(1, len(value)):
    zerocrossing = 0
    if ((value[i-1]) > 0 and value[i] < 0):
        zerocrossing += 1
    if ((value[i-1]) < 0 and value[i] > 0):
        zerocrossing += 1
stdio.writeln('The Number of Zero Crossings is ' + str(zerocrossing))
```

This code doesn't give me any errors, but it's not giving me the right answer. If I give it the input `[1.0, -1.0, 1.0]` it gives me `1`, but it should give `2`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `zerocrossing` to zero at *every* loop iteration. Move `zerocrossing = 0` outside the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1.0, -1.0, 1.0]

zero_x = 0

for idx, item in enumerate(l[:-1]):
    if l[idx] < 0 and l[idx+1] > 0:
        zero_x +=1
    if l[idx] > 0 and l[idx+1] < 0:
        zero_x +=1
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Comment: This solution doesn't work when there are 0 in the list. Can do a filtering before the for loop. `l = [a for a in l if a != 0]`

Comment: arent we comparing one index to the next , or is this an accumulating run @EricWang

Comment: @EricWang in OP func appears he is only comparing one index to its next index

Comment: Yeah I think the description of the problem is a little unclear. OP didn't really explain the definition of zero crossing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already identified, your immediate problem is that you are initializing your counter inside the loop, causing it to reset to zero on each iteration.

The comment was raised in another answer that the algorithm doesn't account for lists that contains one or more zeros. This can be solved by filtering, or by something like the below, if for some reason you wouldn't want to filter the list.

I'm a bit rusty at python, so there are likely more pythonic ways to achieve this.

```
l = [1.0, 0.0, -1.0,0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

def zero_x(l):
    x =0       #Count
    s0=0; s1=0 #This and next sign
    sign = lambda a: (a>0) - (a<0)  
    cross = lambda a,b,lim: (s0 !=lim and s1!=lim and s0 !=s1)

    for idx, item in enumerate(l[:-1]):
        s0=s0 if l[idx]==0 else sign(l[idx])  #Keep previous sign if zero
        s1=sign(l[idx+1])
        x+=cross(s0,s1,0)

    return x

print(zero_x(l))
```